# where can I use aren't?

Tags: contractions

where I have to use **aren't** ? can I use "aren't" when I'm talking about clothes? example; " aren't this blouses a little expensive?" is it right?

Answer (score 2):

Your use of *aren't* is correct, although you need "these blouses", not "this blouses". If you want to refer to a single item, you need to use *isn't*. *Aren't* is a contraction is *are not*, and *isn't* is a contraction of *is not*.

- Aren't these blouses a little expensive?
- Isn't this blouse a little expensive?

Comment: Or if you wanna be too informal you could use **ain't** for either *plural* or *singular*.

Answer (score 1):

Mick probably gave you the answer you need, but a broader answer to when you can use "aren't" is that you can use it in present tense negative with the second-person singular and first-, second-, and third-persons plural:

Second-person singular: You aren't.
First-person plural: We aren't.
Second-person plural: You aren't.
Third-person plural: They aren't. (Also, "These blouses aren't.")

All of these become negative interrogative simply by reversing their order. And in a fluke of English, you can also use aren't in present tense negative interrogative with the first-person singular: "Aren't I?" Although, if you didn't use a contraction, you'd conjugate it as "Am I not?"